# XML Parsing gives me an Error then crashes application

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I am creating a simple Login page that will respond to response given from REST service. The response if given back in XML and have checked via a browser that the service is working fine.

Every time i click the Login button the application force closes, i have debugged it but still cant figure it out.

startLogin has been changed to an AsyncTask

In the Main activity is where i call to startLogin on my button click listener.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.loginButton).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            new startLogin().execute("");
        }
    });
}
```

The below is the Async Task i created

```
private class startLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        final EditText User= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
        final EditText Pass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        final TextView testLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testLabel);
          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String finished= "have finished the login task.";
            int z = 0;
            String username = User.getText().toString();
            String password = Pass.getText().toString();
            String getOne = "http://demo.relocationmw.com/ws_docmgmt/mobile.asmx/GetLogin?userName=";
            String getTwo = "&passWord=";
            String URL = getOne + username + getTwo + password;  
            String KEY_ITEM = "Response";
            String KEY_SUCCESS = "Success";
            String KEY_FAIL = "Fail";
            String KEY_UID = "UID";
            testLabel.setText("Success to Async");
            String xml = getXMLFromUrl(URL);
            Document doc = getDomElement(xml);

            if(xml != null)
            {
                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(z);
                String successString = getValue(e,KEY_SUCCESS);
                String UIDString = getValue(e,KEY_UID);
                String failString = getValue(e,KEY_FAIL);
                String loginError = "Please check username and password.";
                if(failString.equals("Fail")){
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, loginError, duration);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else{
                    if(successString.equals("Success")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }else
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Connection to Retrieve Data.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            return finished;
          }      

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
          }

          @Override
          protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
          }

    //XML Parsing Start
        public String getXMLFromUrl(String url){
            String xml = null;
            try{
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return xml;
        }

        public Document getDomElement(String xml){
            Document doc = null;
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {

                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                    doc = db.parse(is); 

                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
                    // return DOM
                return doc;
        }

        public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
            NodeList n = ((Document) item).getElementsByTagName(str);
            return getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }

        public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
                 Node child;
                 if( elem != null){
                     if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                         for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                             if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                                 return child.getNodeValue();
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 return "";
          }
    //XML Parsing Stop

    }
 }
```

XML "MainActivity":

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/BackgroundGrey"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:text="@string/loginbuttonlabel" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text|textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text|textPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat Errors:

```
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:823)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:318)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15468)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6313)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3567)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3425)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3400)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at com.testingapp.MainActivity$startLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:83)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at com.testingapp.MainActivity$startLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-20 02:56:39.927: E/AndroidRuntime(1018):     ... 3 more
```

I was able to get the problem narrowed to the Async Activity now.
Any Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post your logcat output?  Did you try walking through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Strings shouldn't be compared `==` by the way. Use `.equals()`

Comment: Please add the XML or the log otherwise there is just too many things that could be wrong and we would be giving you bad advice

Comment: Updated. Appreciate everyone trying to help!

Comment: "gives me an error" with absolutely no information about what the error is, an error message, or any other relevant details, and posting a big chunk of code with "please figure out what's wrong" is not an answerable question here. Questions here need to be **specific**, with the **relevant** portions of the code included. Please edit your question to provide more information about the error itself, and remove all the unnecessary code. Expecting us to guess what the error might be and what section of the code it might be in is simply inconsiderate, especially when you're asking for free help.

Comment: Also a rude reply is not needed. @Ken White I updated the information that everyone asked for, i don't know where the error is coming from either or i would have fixed it..I'm asking for help not looking for a pissing contest. If you have an idea of what might be best to post on here why don't you make suggestions?

Comment: There was nothing rude in my reply. The FAQ here clearly says you should ask *specific* questions, and "gives me an error" is clearly not meaningful without information about what "an error" means. If you don't understand that, try calling your doctor and saying "I have a pain. What's wrong?" and see if you get a diagnosis or treatment. There's no "pissing contest". Learn to use the debugger to at least narrow down the area of the code the problem is located in, and describe the problem you're trying to solve. (I could have just downvoted or voted to close your question instead.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private class startLogin extends AsyncTask  {

```
 @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    return getXMLFromUrl(params[0]);
}

@Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     if(result != null) {
     String xml = result;
     Document doc = getDomElement(xml);
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(z);
            String successString = getValue(e,KEY_SUCCESS);
            String UIDString = getValue(e,KEY_UID);
            String failString = getValue(e,KEY_FAIL);
            String loginError = "Please check username and password.";
            if(failString.equals("Fail")){
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, loginError, duration);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
            else{
                if(successString.equals("Success")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }else
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Connection to Retrieve Data.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

}
```

}

// Call asynctask
new startlogin().execute(URL);

Comment: Mine looks a little different but does exactly the same thing. I took out getXMLFromURL and ran it in the background task moving all the UI element changes and functions in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

Let put your getXMLFromUrl() method in a new thread (ex: AsyncTask).

Comment: Could you hihglight on this a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I've not read your code, but the stack trace includes `No address associated with hostname` - I'd start there.

Try putting your constructed URL into a browser, wget or whatever you prefer and see that the request actually returns something. When you can see the results you expect, then weave it into your code. Also, make sure your code is making the same request.

Comment: Yes, both in my code and in a browser i have tested it. The code crashes the application and the browser returns the XML i need. One being "Fail" and another "Success"

Answer (score 0):

class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return getXMLFromUrl(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: i updated the code, could you look at it now and let me know if that's better. It still force closes the application.